# golang channel can't consume or publish

Tags: go, channel

In my code below,just part of the whole code.I init a channel, the channel can't consume or publish.I don't konw what make this happen.

```
//init at the beginning of program
var stopSvr chan bool
stopSvr=make(chan bool)
var stopSvrDone chan bool
stopSvrDone=make(chan bool)

//somewhere use,in a goroutine
select{
    case <-stopSvr:
        stopSvrDone<-true
        fmt.Println("son svr exit")
    default:
        //do its job
}

//somewhere use,in a goroutine
stopSvr <- true //block here
<-stopSvrDone
fmt.Println("svr exit")

//here to do other things,but it's blocked at "stopSvr<-true",
//what condition could make this happen?
```

conclusion:
channel's block and unblock,I didn't know clearly.
select{} expr keyword 'default',I didn't know clearly.
that's why my program didn't run.

thanks @jimt ,I finish the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. But your example code is guaranteed to block on the select statement.

The `default` case for a select is used to provide a fallback when either a specific read or write on a channel does not succeed. This means that in your code, the default case is always executed. No value is ever written into the channel before the select begins, thus the `case` statement is never run.

The code in the `default` case will never succeed and block indefinitely, because there is no space in the channel to store the value and nobody else is reading from it in any other goroutines.

A simple solution to your immediate problem would be:

```
stopSvr=make(chan bool, 1) // 1 slot buffer to store a value
```

However, without understanding what you want to achieve, I can't guarantee that this will solve all your problems.

Comment: I'm sorry about that I didn't describe my question well,now I fix it.I really have no idea to find the answer,because I really get to start to use go for a short time.  @jimt

Comment: It's still not very clear.. But your code now blocks on the `stopSvrDone<-true` as you mentioned. That happens for the same reason as the `stopSvr` channel problem. I suggest you read up on how channels work in Go before you try using them: http://tour.golang.org/#67 and http://blog.golang.org/pipelines may help.